Discord.js convert user_id (stored in db) in username
So i have stored discord user_ids in a database and retrive them. I confirm that if got them with a
console.log(submitted_by_id);

and I get <userid> in the console. After that i try to .username the submitted_by_id.
let submitted_by = submitted_by_id.username;

and output submitted_by in the console, but now i get a undefined in the console.
Full Code:
let submitted_by_id = newQuote[0].submited_by_id; //submitted_by_id = user_id
let submitted_by = submitted_by_id.username;

console.log(submitted_by_id);
console.log(submitted_by);

I tryed to use:
let user = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(submitted_by_id);

but this can only return cached users (so I've read) and also returnes a undefined for me.

So I've got the answer myself, you have to change
let submitted_by_id = newQuote[0].submited_by_id; //submitted_by_id = user_id

in
let submitted_by_id = await interaction.client.users.fetch(newQuote[0].submited_by_id); //submitted_by_id = user_id

than it will work.
